# Is this the solution of the fourth Landau's problem correct?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

First, consider that to prove that there infinitely many primes of the form $p=n^2+1$, consider that if we select a $c \in \Bbb N$, $c>0$, that if we say, for example, that $c=4$, and we want to prove there are infinitely many primes of the form $p=4n+l$, proving that, is equivalent to proving $p-l=4n$, so, consider $p, p-1, p-2, p-3$, since there are 4 numbers in here, and one is the successor of the other, one of them has to be a multiple of four, (assuming that $p$ is odd), we can say neither $p$, neither $p-2$ are multiples of four, but $p-1$ and $p-3$ can be. So, we have just proven that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $p=4n+1$ and also, of the form $p=4n+3$.

But using this argument, we can prove that there are infinitely many prime numbers of the form $p=cn+1$, where $c>1$, can such a thing mean, that if we say $c=n$, we'll have a proof of the fourth Landau problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you did *not* prove that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+1$ and that there are infinitely many primes of the form $4n+3$. All that you proved was that there are infinitey many numbers $n$ such that $4n+1$ is prime or $4n+3$ is prime.

Now, suppose that it is true that, for each $c\in\mathbb N$, there are infinitely many $n$'s such that $cn+1$ is prime (by the way, this is true, by a [theorem due to Dirichlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions)). Can you jump from here to the assertion that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2+1$ just by taking $c=n$? No, you cannot. If you could, then you could also jump from the fact that there are, for each $c\in\mathbb N$, infinitely many primes of the form $cn-1$ (which is also true) to the conclusien that there are infinitely many primes of the form $n^2-1$. However, since $n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$, $n^2-1$ is *never* a prime number, unless $n=2$.

Comment: How do you actually know that if using the things I proposed, we **having** a proof of the fourth Landau problem is equivalent to saying that, we have a proof that there are infinitely many primes of the form $p=n^2-1$? That does not make much sense to me.

Comment: And if you could explain, or link me to the proof of the Dirichlet theorem of which you referenced, I'd be thankful.

Comment: I have added a link to Dirichlet's theorem.

Comment: Concerning your first comment, I did **not** say what you claim there. What I wrote was that if you think that we can jum from $cn+1$ to $n^2+1$ just by taking $c=n$, then you should also think that we can jump from $cn-1$ to $n^2-1$.